# QGIS forcing labels for separate feature parts into the same part

Tags: qgis, labeling, features, multipart

I have noticed that if there is a feature that has very small parts in addition to a "main" part, and you have checked the boxes for both 1) "label every part of multi-part features" and 2) "only draw label if it fits completely within polygon", it will sometimes force the "part label" into a different, larger part. See this example on the Birmingham, Alabama area. Birmingham, Irondale, and Mountain Brook all do have multiple parts. However, the labels are all within the same part. Is there a way to avoid this without turning off either of the checkboxes I previously mentioned or separating the parts into distinct features? This is some seriously annoying functionality, and I don't understand why anybody would want a part label in the wrong part. I have only observed this to happen with "Horizontal" or "Free" labeling, although it might happen with other labeling styles.

[image]